# Magento 2 : Assets with specifc string in file name 404 in admin

Tags: magento2.2, apache, hosting

Got a strange scenario on magento install

A couple of assets in the backend 404 which means you can't edit products

```
/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/variations/variations.js
/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/Magento_Variable/variables.js
```

The only reason we can can see is because they contain the string `var` in the name.

If you rename them they load.

Can't figure out why.

- cPanel server
- Apache
- php 7.1
- Magento 2.2.3

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried redeploying your site? before you redeploy again delete the var/view_processed folder and this should create a whole new version in magento if you still have issues it may be a permission issue on the server

Comment: @DavaGordon Yes.  Migrated files to another server and it works fine.  Deployment works. Themes are compiling. Files exist. Permissions are correct.  Renaming either so doesn't contain the string `var` and they load - so to clarify same file / same location. So it's something specific to hosting for this website and/or htaccess and the string `var`.

Comment: I had an issue with 2.2 a while back can you switch from production to developer and back just want to see if its been fixed.

Comment: @DavaGordon switched from production to developer and back again and still same issue

Comment: so you have run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB -f

Comment: @DavaGordon Yes.  Plus also switching modes just performed the same.

Comment: Have you spoken to your host regarding this as sounds more like a server related issue rather than a magento issue possibly a indexer blacklist in place on the server. if you try locally and it works then they is most certainly going to be the issue

Comment: @DavaGordon Yes. Currently in discussion. Although so far no progress - I think they're scratching their heads too. My colleague has potentially ruled out apache mod_security. It was more just a faint hope that someone somewhere had experienced same issue as it immediately breaks product edit in backend.

Comment: are you using versioning? you can check this by seeing if dev/static/sign exists in the config table

Comment: @DavaGordon No. It was on but we turned it off to rule out that as an issue plus give something simpler that our hosts could debug.  Also as we've been messing around with theme deployment - so I didn't want to have to continually bump the version number in our testing

Comment: Found that to be a massive pain but usually tends to work in production

Comment: @DavaGordon just to confirm the issue exists with dev/static/sign set on either value.  This is after recompiling theme and clearing caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our hosts managed to track down the source of the issue

There was an apache magento.conf file buried in the cPanel file system under userdata for this particular user which essentially had a wildcard value which meant that anything that contained the string 'var' was set to deny

It's path went something like this

`./conf.d/userdata/std/[apache_version]/[username]/[domain]/magento.conf`

`./conf.d/userdata/ssl/[apache_version]/[username]/[domain]/magento.conf`

No idea on how or why.  I can't be more specific as I'm relaying information and I didn't get to see the file contents.

Hope this helps someone one day and helps you rule out an issue with Magento much quicker and you can get on to the hosts.